Casting VLC from a Pixel to 2 paired Nest audio speakers halts before the playlist has ended
Happens on a Pixel 6a and 8 Pro
The MP3s are in the Internal Storage > Music folder.
I created a VLC playlist and selected these tracks.
The playlist looks fine.
However, everytime I play the playlist, only about 3 or 4 out of about 16 tracks will play before I have to reclick the cast icon and select the paired Nest speakers again.
Some times it will resume casting itself after a delay of 5 minutes or so.
Help appreciated.

In VLC settings -> Casting, activating Audio Passthrough solved the problem.


Sounds like it could be the Android battery optimization putting the app to sleep after a while of inactivity. This feature is known to cause this issue in VLC.
You can disable Battery Optimization for each app individually. Here are the steps for Android 13 and 14.

Settings > Apps > VLC > App battery usage > Choose "Unrestricted".
Alternatively: Long tap VLC > App info > App battery usage > "Unrestricted".

The steps for Android 11 are provided in the VLC ticket. Hope that helps!

Thanks for your help. VLC has unrestricted already

Sorry that didn't solve it. What I would try is to see if it is the same using a different player app, for example Ampache. If it is the same, I would try it with a different speaker, to narrow down the problem in a simple way.

Thanks, I can't find Ampache in the Play store
